# Why this grid layout is having only two rows and how to make it 3 and have this pattern?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm learning grid-layout on w3schools and I encountered a problem with understanding the grid-template-areas.
I created 3 grid-area items a, b and c and tried to make a layout that would have 3 rows and 5 columns. Firstly it would have two fractions "a" in the first two rows/columns which would make a small square in the top-left corner, below that square in the third row occupying 2 fractions would be a horizonal bar, and in each of the 3 rows there would be 3 fractions "b" that would form a big square. This is the pattern I want to achieve ('row1' 'row2' 'row3'):

'a a b b b'
'a a b b b'
'c c b b b'

This is the result I'm getting after executing the code below:

[image: This is the result of what I'm getting.]

```css
.item1 {
  grid-area: a;
}

.item2 {
  grid-area: b;
}

.item3 {
  grid-area: c;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'a a b b b' 'a a b b b' 'c c b b b';
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">a</div>
  <div class="item2">b</div>
  <div class="item3">c</div>
</div>
```

I tried to use different patterns for grid-template-areas as well as trying to use grid-template-rows. I searched a couple of tutorials on YouTube that would cover this issue without luck.

Comment: Just defining rows and columns will not make then **square** by default. You have to set sizes to do that.

Comment: What more were you expecting? CSS Grids does not generate content; it lays out existing content according to rules you give it, unless you provide more content (e.g. with the `content` property).

Comment: When I was trying to accomplish this layout I simply edited this W3schools piece of code : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_grid-template-areas3 . In this example there isn't any size defined for any of the elements except the padding and the size of the content inside but this kind of layout is still accomplished. I though one could just edit grid-template-areas with an appropriate pattern. It works and I was able to make some 2 row combinations but not 3 rows.